# Which character encoding should I use to download a string to a file, and preserve "\n"?

Tags: dart

In my web-app, I use this code to download a string to a file on local disc:

```
void downloadFile(String filename, String text){
    AnchorElement tl = document.createElement('a');
    tl..attributes['href'] = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + Uri.encodeComponent(text)
        ..attributes['download'] = filename
        ..click();
}
```

but this removes all newline characters ("\n"). What do I need to do to preserve them?

Answer (score 1):

As of Dart 1.14, there's a [`UriData`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.15.0/dart-core/UriData-class.html) class that makes it much easier to work with `data:` URIs. You can use it here like so:

```
void downloadFile(String filename, String text){
  AnchorElement tl = document.createElement('a');
  var href = UriData.fromString(text, encoding: UTF8);
  tl..attributes['href'] = href.toString()
    ..attributes['download'] = filename
    ..click();
```

It should ensure that the proper encoding is used to preserve newlines.

Comment: Character encoding such as `utf-8` vs `iso-8859-1` etc have little to do with newline preservation. `\n` is a symbolic newline, which might be 0x0a `LF` (linefeed) or 0x0d `CR` (carriage-return) or the sequence 0x0d0x0a `CRLF` depending on context.  What's important is _text_ mode that may translate newlines, vs _binary_ mode which preserves bytes exactly as they are, which I assume is the function of `UriData` -- prevent all re-jiggering of characters and present the data as-is.

Comment: Thank. I tried the above. I inserted "new" (var href = new UriData...), but what do I do with that object? I've tried href.contentText, contentAsBytes etc, but no luck.

Comment: You can use `href.uri` to get `Uri` object. Instead you could use `Uri.dataFromString` to create a `Uri` object directly, instead of a `UriData` object: `var href = new Uri.dataFromString(theString, encoding: UTF8);`. (There is no need to specify "text/plain", and you should use `encoding` to specify the charset instead of using a parameter - it's also safer against typos).

Comment: I've updated my code sample to use `encoding` directly. I'm just calling `toString()` on the `UriData` object to get the href.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this again, but I'm afraid this still removes the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is too big, `data:` Uri causes the browser to signals a "download error".

Create a temporary Blob instead and newlines should be still preserved:

```
AnchorElement tl = document.createElement('a');
var href = Url.createObjectUrl(new Blob([text]));
tl..attributes['href'] = href
  ..attributes['download'] = filename
  ..click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get "data:text/html" to work at all (I am no expert), so I use "data:text/csv", and download a csv file.  If users need a text file, they can open it in a spreadsheet and export. It actually suits my purposes.

```
void downloadFile(String filename, String text) {
  text=text.replaceAll('\n','%0A');
  text=text.replaceAll('\t','%2C');
  text="data:text/csv,"+text;
  AnchorElement tl = document.createElement('a');
  tl
  ..attributes['href'] = text
  ..attributes['download'] = filename
  ..click();
}
```

and I would call it:

```
String s="one two \n three four \n five\tsix\t 7";
downloadFile('test.csv',s);
```

If you:

```
downloadFile('test.txt',s);
```

the newlines and tabs are ripped out.